# Single SQL statement that locates one value based on the results of another value

Tags: sql-server

Without using a subquery, I am attempting to locate the manager of a specific department and then the manager of that department manager. Is this possible or is a subquery required?

```
SELECT M. EmployeeFirstName, M. EmployeeLastName
FROM EMPLOYEE_t M, EMPLOYEE_t E
WHERE E.ManagerID = M.EmployeeID
AND E.EmployeeJobTitle = 'Accountant'
GROUP BY M. EmployeeFirstName, M. EmployeeLastName
```

This code provided returns the department manager but I'm not sure how to located the manager of that department manager in a single statement.

Comment: Use a `JOIN` and then filter by your `WHERE`. Please provide the table schemas and how the department manager and the manager of that person are related via the table schemas.

Comment: Sure. Just join `EMPLOYEE_t` in once more and join it to `M.ManagerID`

Comment: You can achieve it with an additional join but please stop using those joins and start using ANSI-92 compliant JOINS.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

Just keep joining `Employee_t`. Two other things:

1. I'm not sure you need the GROUP BY
2. Use ANSI-92 joins

```
SELECT M.EmployeeFirstName
     , M.EmployeeLastName
     , M2.EmployeeFirstName AS ManagerFirstName
     , M2.EmployeeLastName  AS ManagerLastName
FROM EMPLOYEE_t E
JOIN EMPLOYEE_t M
  ON E.ManagerID = M.EmployeeID
JOIN EMPLOYEE_t M2
  ON M.ManagerID = M2.EmployeeID
WHERE E.EmployeeJobTitle = 'Accountant'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rewrite of your current query that retrieves the name of the accountants' manager's manager, rewritten using INNER JOIN (ANSI-92 syntax)

```
SELECT 
    MM.EmployeeFirstName, 
    MM.EmployeeLastName
FROM EMPLOYEE_t M
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_t E
    ON E.ManagerID = M.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_t MM
    ON M.ManagerId = MM.EmployeeID
WHERE E.EmployeeJobTitle = 'Accountant'
GROUP BY MM.EmployeeFirstName, MM.EmployeeLastName
```

The use of GROUP BY can be replaced with the keyword DISTINCT at the top of the query to only return each manager only once, e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    MM.EmployeeFirstName, 
    MM.EmployeeLastName
FROM EMPLOYEE_t M
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_t E
    ON E.ManagerID = M.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_t MM
    ON M.ManagerId = MM.EmployeeID
WHERE E.EmployeeJobTitle = 'Accountant'
```

Additionally, if not all Accountant's managers have managers, you may want to return the name of the highest level manager that you can find. In this case, you can use `ISNULL()` and a `LEFT JOIN` to return the correct top level manager name, i.e.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ISNULL(MM.EmployeeFirstName, M.EmployeeFirstName) as EmployeeFirstName,
    ISNULL(MM.EmployeeLastName, M.EmployeeLastName) as EmployeeLastName
FROM EMPLOYEE_t M
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_t E
    ON E.ManagerID = M.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_t MM
    ON M.ManagerId = MM.EmployeeID
WHERE E.EmployeeJobTitle = 'Accountant'
```